# ProxyChains-NG couldnt locate libproxychains4.so

Tags: proxy, http-proxy, socks

I installed `ProxyChains-NG` on an Ubuntu 14.04, configure, compile, install, I did just what the installation instruction said and I got a trouble.

when I typed `proxychains4 ping google.com`

```
[proxychains] config file found: /usr/local/etc/proxychains.conf
couldnt locate libproxychains4.so
```

and I found there are two files named libproxychains4.so, the directories are:

```
/usr/local/lib/libproxychains4.so
/home/teruun/tools/proxychains-ng/libproxychains4.so
```

What should I do to make it work? I searched on Google but couldn't find something useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got same question when i use proxychains4.

i think the same way that you did like me.
to customize prefix path.

reconfigure the path and use default.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc
make
sudo make install
sudo make install-config #(generate proxychains4 conf file if none,/etc/proxychains.conf)
```

there is my proxylist

```
[ProxyList]
socks5  127.0.0.1 1080
```

terminal print:

```
jeiao@ins:~$ proxychains4 ping www.google.com
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/libproxychains4.so
```

Answer (score 1):

### git clone project

```
git clone https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng
cd proxychains-ng
```

### see configure command help doc

```
$ ./configure --help
supported arguments
--prefix=/path            default: /usr/local
--exec_prefix=/path       default: /usr/local/bin
--bindir=/path            default: /usr/local/bin
--libdir=/path            default: /usr/local/lib
--includedir=/path        default: /usr/local/include
--sysconfdir=/path        default: /usr/local/etc
--ignore-cve              default: no
    if set to yes ignores CVE-2015-3887 and makes it possible
    to preload from current dir (possibly insecure, but handy)
--fat-binary : build for both i386 and x86_64 architectures on 64-bit Macs
--fat-binary-m1 : build for both arm64e and x86_64 architectures on M1 Macs
--hookmethod=dlsym|dyld   hook method for osx. default: auto
  if OSX >= 12 is detected, dyld method will be used if auto.
--help : show this text
```

### default configure `--libdir=/usr/local/lib`

```
$ ./configure --fat-binary-m1
checking whether C compiler works ... yes
checking whether libc headers are complete ... yes
checking whether C compiler understands -Wno-unknown-pragmas ... yes
checking whether getnameinfo() servlen argument is POSIX compliant (socklen_t) ... yes
checking whether we have GNU-style getservbyname_r() ... no
checking whether we have pipe2() and O_CLOEXEC ... no
checking whether we have SOCK_CLOEXEC ... no
checking whether we have clock_gettime ... yes
checking whether $CC defines __APPLE__ ... yes
checking whether $CC defines __x86_64__ ... no
checking whether $CC defines __FreeBSD__ ... no
checking whether $CC defines __OpenBSD__ ... no
checking whether $CC defines __sun ... no
checking whether $CC defines __HAIKU__ ... no
checking whether we can use -Wl,--no-as-needed ... no
checking what's the option to use in linker to set library name ... -install_name
checking checking whether we can use -ldl ... yes
checking checking whether we can use -lpthread ... yes
using Monterey style DYLD hooking
Configuring a fat binary for arm64[e] and x86_64
Done, now run make && make install
...
```

### make && make install

```
$ make && make install
...
./tools/install.sh -D -m 644 libproxychains4.dylib /usr/local/lib/libproxychains4.dylib
./tools/install.sh -D -m 755 proxychains4 /usr/local/bin/proxychains4
./tools/install.sh -D -m 755 proxychains4-daemon /usr/local/bin/proxychains4-daemon
```

now you can see the library storage at `/usr/local/lib/libproxychains4.dylib`

### Proxychains config

```
$ cat proxychains.conf
round_robin_chain
proxy_dns

remote_dns_subnet 224
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000

[ProxyList]
socks5  127.0.0.1   10553
```

### Usage proxychains

```
$ /usr/local/bin/proxychains4 telnet ipinfo.io 443
[proxychains] config file found: /opt/homebrew/services/proxychains/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/local/lib/libproxychains4.dylib
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.16-git-13-g133e06b
Trying 34.117.59.81...
[proxychains] Dynamic chain  ...  127.0.0.1:10553  ...  34.117.59.81:443  ...  OK
Connected to ipinfo.io.
Escape character is '^]'
```